# Error when raising custom event

Tags: c#, events, delegates, custom-events

I have a class that will write a log. The class needs to raise an event (under specific circumstances not indicated below), that will be comsumed by a class to react on it.  I have the code below but as soon as I try to raise the event, I get an error on the line as indicated, that

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Any idea what I'm missing?

```
//1. Class where event is registered
    public class LogEvent
    {
        public delegate void WriteLogEventHandler(object Sender, WriteLogEventArgs e);
        public event WriteLogEventHandler WriteLog;

        public class WriteLogEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public string Message { get; set; }

            public WriteLogEventArgs(string message) : base()
            {
                Message = message;
            }
        }

        //Raise the event.
        internal void OnWriteLog(WriteLogEventArgs e)
        {
             WriteLog(this, e);    //Error here.  Seems like WriteLog is null
        }

//2. Class where event is raised.
public class Logs
{
    public static void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        LogEvent.WriteLogEventArgs args = new LogEvent.WriteLogEventArgs(message);
        new LogEvent().OnWriteLog(args);
    }
}

//3. Class where event should be consumed
public class MyClass()
{
    private LogEvent _logEvent;
    public MyClass()
        {
            //Subscribe to event:
            _logEvent = new LogEvent();
            _logEvent.WriteLog += (sender, args) => { DoSomething(args.Message); };
        }

   public void DoSomething(string message)
   { ... }
}
```

Comment: When you do `new LogEvent().OnWriteLog(args);` in `WriteLog(string message)` you create a new instance of `LogEvent` that doesn't have `WriteLog` wired up to a handler, so of course it's still null. Also in the `MyClass` constructor you create a`LogEvent` and wire up `WriteLog` but then don't store instance of `LogEvent` anywhere.

Comment: Makes sense. I thought something like that and have tried a few scenarios but no success yet. I feel too stupid to ask for a code example so I'll keep on trying for now :)

Comment: Part 2 of your answer is partially in my code, but not in the question.  Will update question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- You're raising the event whether or not anyone has subscribed to it. Don't do that - you *will* get a `NullReferenceException` if you call `WriteLog(this, e)` when `WriteLog` is null. In C# 6 it's easy to avoid this:

  ```
  WriteLog?.Invoke(this, e);
  ```
- You're subscribing to the event on a different `LogEvent` instance than the one which is raising the event. This is more of a design issue than anything else - it makes no sense for an individual log event to have a list of subscribers. Instead, you should have a `Logger` or similar which has the subscribers (via an event), then each `LogEvent` is passed to those subscribers. You'd create *one* `Logger`, subscribe to it, then call `WriteLog` on the same instance.

Comment: Point 1 is very handy thanks (although it should be WriteLog?.Invoke and not WriteLine.Invoke).  Point 2 I'm not sure yet how to solve. As per feedback to Michael I feel too stupid to ask for a code example so I'll keep on trying for now :).  Thanks for the answer.